# array output var_dump and echo contradiction PHP

Tags: php, arrays, printing, output

I have a problem in array output, following is my output of a 2D array in var_dump, but when I echo this array, it only shows total 9 indexes total, instead of showing 9 9 9 indexes of 3 rows of multi-dimensional array.
Output of `var_dump`

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=11)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      2 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      3 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      4 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      5 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      6 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      7 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      8 => string 'Mining' (length=6)
      9 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      10 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=11)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string 'Abc<p class="tr3 td26">' (length=23)
      2 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      3 => string 'Ahsan<p class="tr3 td26">' (length=25)
      4 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      5 => string 'mm<p class="tr3 td26">' (length=22)
      6 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      7 => string 'oo<p class="tr3 td26">' (length=22)
      8 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
      9 => string 'kk<p class="tr3 td26">' (length=22)
      10 => string '<p class=" td26">' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=11)
      0 => string 'Fical' (length=5)
      1 => string '2005-06' (length=7)
      2 => string '2006-07' (length=7)
      3 => string '2007-08' (length=7)
      4 => string '2008-09' (length=7)
      5 => string '2009-10' (length=7)
      6 => string '2010-11' (length=7)
      7 => string '2011-12' (length=7)
      8 => string '2012-13' (length=7)
      9 => string 'Change' (length=6)
      10 => string 'Change2' (length=7)
```

**Output of echo:**

```
Abc
Ahsan
mm
oo
kk
Fical
2005-06
2006-07
2007-08
2008-09
2009-10
```

10 is my limit defined in some variable, but the problem is, when I print the values less than 10, they are printed well (obviously), but not exceeding 10, what should i do/review ?

bug code (having said bug):

```
foreach($d as $k=>$v){

  if(($v=='')&&($k!==0)){

    $d[$k].="<p class=\" td26\">" ;
    $d[$k-1].="<p class=\"tr3 td26\">" ;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
foreach($d as $k=>$v){
  if(($v=='')&&($k!==0)){
    $d[$k].="<p class=\" td26\">" ;
    $d[$k-1].="<p class=\"tr3 td26\">" ;
   }
}
```

Why are you setting `$d[$k]` and then immediately after that setting `$d[$k-1]`? The `$k-1` effectively overwrites your previous value?  Why not do this instead:

```
foreach($d as $k=>$v){
  if(($v=='')&&($k!==0)){
    $d[$k].="<p class=\" td26\">"
          . "<p class=\"tr3 td26\">"
          ;
   }
}
```

Unless I am missing the goal of your code entirely?

Comment: beacuse i need an underlined from the array index and also its previous indexes except 0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this script on a browser or on the command line?

If you are on a browser, it's quite normal, since printing a string like

```
 <p class="td26">
```

will not be visible at all... :-)

More, you *can't* use echo to print the values of an array (you should obtain only the string "Array"...).

You should probably better explain what you are trying to obtain...

Comment: will visible, i tried .. :P ;)

Comment: what do you see, with '<p class="td26">' in HTML? :-)

Comment: You should open the source of the page, to see it... :-)

Comment: its basically adding a custom underline from the array index. thats Y .. its working great with less than 10 values btw .. ;)

Comment: A "custom underline" ?

Comment: means underline .. in simple words, spaces with under line